# スプレッドシートのQueryで、ある列の値が条件を満たすものの合計と、総合計を同時に求めたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Googleスプレッドシートにて、在庫表を作っています。
シート1は入出庫履歴が蓄積されていくシートで、シート2は在庫表になってます。
専用アプリから入力したデータがシート1に自動で蓄積されていきます。

シート1には下記内容が入っています。
[image: シート1]

シート2にQueryでシート1のA列の品名ごとにB列、C列の合計を持ってきたいです。
ただ、B列はD列が「入庫処理」のもののみの合計を持ってきたく、C列はD列関係なく表示されているものすべての合計を持ってきたいです。

下記関数までは組めたのですが、これだとC列もD列が「入庫処理」のものの合計になってしまいます。

`=QUERY('シート1'!A1:D,"select A, sum(B), sum(C) where D='入庫処理' and A is not null group by A  label A '品名', sum(B) '合計', sum(C) '引当数'", 1)`

[image: シート2]

結果のイメージとしては下記のような結果で表示してほしいです。
（C列はシート1のＤ列関係なく合計したいので、製品Aの引当数が10ではなく、15になってほしい）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何か少しでもアドバイス頂けますと有難いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

＊＊＊

（7/13追記）

Tanaike様

パターン２の関数を実際に使っているシートにあてはめました。
　　　　　例　　実際
品名　　：A列　　E列
数量　　：B列　　Q列
引当数　：C列　　K列
入荷済み：D列　　P列

※質問に記載した列と実際のシートの列が違っていてすみません。

=QUERY(BYROW('シート１'!A1:S,LAMBDA(value1,{index(value1,1,5),if(index(value1,1,16)="",0,index(value1,1,17)),index(value1,1,11),index(value1,1,16)})),"select Col5, sum(Col17), sum(Col11) where Col5 is not null group by Col5 label Col5 '品名', sum(Col17) '合計', sum(Col11) '引当数'", 1)

エラーが発生してしまったのですが、なぜだか分かりますでしょうか。
エラー内容
「関数 QUERY のパラメータ 2 のクエリ文字列を解析できません: NO_COLUMN: Col5」
※Col5　を　E　などに変えても同じエラーが出てしまいました。

また、BYROWやLAMBDAなどを使うのが初めてのため、そのあたりの使い方も間違っているかもしれません。
合わせてご確認頂けますと幸いです。

以上よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

例えば、次の2パターンはいかがでしょうか。

#### パターン1

このパターンでは、列A-Cを列A,Bと列Cに分けて出力します。

```
={QUERY('シート1'!A1:D,"select A, sum(B) where D='入庫処理' and A is not null group by A label A '品名', sum(B) '合計'", 1),QUERY('シート1'!A1:D,"select sum(C) where A is not null group by A label sum(C) '引当数'", 1)}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### パターン2

このパターンでは、最初に列Cに"入庫処理"のない列Bを0に変更することで、使用されているQUERY関数では"入庫処理"をチェックする必要がなくなります。

```
=QUERY(BYROW('シート1'!A1:D,LAMBDA(value1,{index(value1,1,1),if(index(value1,1,4)="",0,index(value1,1,2)),index(value1,1,3),index(value1,1,4)})),"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 '品名', sum(Col2) '合計', sum(Col3) '引当数'", 1)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 追加

更新された質問への新たな回答は下記のとおりです。

まず、下記の新たな質問について、

> =QUERY(BYROW('シート１'!A1:S,LAMBDA(value1,{index(value1,1,5),if(index(value1,1,16)="",0,index(value1,1,17)),index(value1,1,11),index(value1,1,16)})),"select Col5, sum(Col17), sum(Col11) where Col5 is not null group by Col5 label Col5 '品名', sum(Col17) '合計', sum(Col11) '引当数'", 1)

> エラーが発生してしまったのですが、なぜだか分かりますでしょうか。

理由は、`BYROW('シート１'!A1:S,LAMBDA(value1,{index(value1,1,5),if(index(value1,1,16)="",0,index(value1,1,17)),index(value1,1,11),index(value1,1,16)}))`で、`'シート1'!A1:S`の列を4列に縮小しているため、`select Col5, sum(Col17), sum(Col11) where Col5 is not null group by Col5 label Col5 '品名', sum(Col17) '合計', sum(Col11) '引当数'`では、存在しない列を選択していることが原因と思われます。

この場合、`BYROW(###)`のみを変更して、queryについては変更する必要はありませんので、下記のように修正してください。

```
=QUERY(BYROW('シート1'!A1:S,LAMBDA(value1,{index(value1,1,5),if(index(value1,1,16)="",0,index(value1,1,17)),index(value1,1,11),index(value1,1,16)})),"select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 '品名', sum(Col2) '合計', sum(Col3) '引当数'", 1)
```

Comment: Tanaike様
回答いただき有難うございます！
コメント遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。

シート１にて例えば製品AのD列「入荷済み」がすべて空白だったり、新しい製品C等を入力した際にエラーとなってしまいました。
エラー内容は「関数 ARRAY_ROW のパラメータ 2 に一致しない行サイズがあります（3 となるべきところが 5 になっています）。」と返ってきています。

しかし、パターン２につきましては、上記対応をしてもエラーなく表示されました！
ただ私の勉強が足りず、なぜこうなっているのかわかっておりませんが、こちらで色々といじってみようかと思います。
ありがとうございました！

Comment: 新しい回答にコメントしました。ご確認頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: @まくまく ご返事ありがとうございます。確認が遅くなり申し訳ありません。`※質問に記載した列と実際のシートの列が違っていてすみません。`から、どうやら表示された質問が実際の内容と異なっていたようですね。表示された質問が実際とは異なることに気づかなかったことをお詫び致します。更新された質問にある追加された質問への回答も含めて追記しましたのでご確認ください。

Comment: QUERYの範囲がBYROWの式にになってるので、BYROWの式の列に該当する列数をCol〇と表示すればよかったのですね！ありがとうございます。そして無事やりたいことが実現できました！ありがとうございました！！新しい関数も学ぶことが出来、とても勉強になりました。もしまた機会がありましたらその際はまたご教授宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @まくまく 無事に解決したとのことで安心しました。ご返事ありがとうございました。